# CakePHP 1.3 - Using RLIKE in model query

Tags: mysql, cakephp, model

I have the following conditions for a model that finds a list of subjects:

```
$subjects = $this->PtlSubject->find('all', array(

    'conditions' => array('PtlSubject.title RLIKE' => '[[:<:]]'.$value),
    'limit' => 6

));
```

When running the query I get a mysql error:

1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '[[:<:]]mat'    LIMIT 6' at line 1

Is there another way you can use REGEX word boundaries for mysql queries in CakePHP?

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if Cake knows how to deal with `RLIKE`. You can always pass the whole condition directly, like this:

```
 'conditions' => "PtlSubject.title RLIKE '[[:<:]]$value'"
```

Just make sure `$value` is properly escaped, to avoid [injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain).